# macOS preview and ffmpeg report different video sizes

Tags: macos, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I have a video which is 886x1920, as I can see from the ffmpeg output:

```
ffmpeg -i en_scaled_2.mp4                                                                 
ffmpeg version 4.3.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.62)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.3.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'en_scaled_2.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
  Duration: 00:00:29.03, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2073 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 886x1920 [SAR 1:1 DAR 443:960], 1936 kb/s, SAR 9991:9992 DAR 281:609, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
```

But macOS Finder's preview reports 885x1920:

[image]

Apple AppStore connect reports that it's not 886 pixels tall too:

[image]

Why, and how to fix it?

// Note: The original video was 885x1920, but I've added 1px at the bottom by overlaying it with 886x1920 transparent image with 1px-tall non-transparent line at the bottom:

```
ffmpeg -i en_scaled.mp4 -i Artboard.png -filter_complex "overlay" -y en_scaled_2.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [pad filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf pad=886:ih -c:a copy output.mp4
```

- overlay will make an output the size of the bottom layer and will exclude any overlap.
- I would have to see the complete log from your command to see how it ended up being 886.

Comment: I had to convert a video with a higher resolution into one with 886x1920 in order to upload it to Apple's App Store. But the `pad` argument had no effect in my case. Eventually, I used the following command to convert that higher resolution video: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -vf scale=886:1920,fps=30 -aspect:v 886:1920 -ar 44100 -crf 18 utput.mp4`